# SQL Why is this join not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT tab4.IRSpot as IRSpot, tab4.IRVol AS MaxPlauShift, tab4.VegElement AS MaxPlauLoss FROM
    (SELECT tab1.IRSpot, MIN(tab1.VegaElement*Probability) AS PlausibleLoss FROM
        (SELECT IRSpot, IRVol, VegaElement 
        FROM SEL_VegaElementMatrix()) tab1
    JOIN
        (SELECT IRSpot, IRVol, Probability 
        FROM Table_Name_2) tab2
    ON tab1.IRSpot = tab2.IRSpot AND tab1.IRVol = tab2.IRVol
    GROUP BY tab1.IRSpot) tab3
JOIN
    (SELECT IRSpot, IRVol, VegaElement 
    FROM SEL_VegaElementMatrix()) tab4
ON tab3.PlausibleLoss = tab4.VegaElement AND tab3.IRSpot = tab4.IRSpot
```

tab3 returns a row {2,0} and tab4 returns many rows, eight of these containing the same values {2,0}.

I am expecting my join to return eight rows of results, as I am performing a JOIN but I am only being returned one result row?

Comment: Why did you delete the body of your question!?  I've rolled it back to show the question to which you accepted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to a RIGHT JOIN to find out what doesn't match.  An INNER JOIN will only display rows where a match is found in both tables.  I suspect it's something in the final where/on clause, but without seeing the tables structures and data, it's difficult to tell.

```
SELECT tab4.IRSpot as IRSpot, tab4.IRVol AS MaxPlauShift, tab4.VegElement AS MaxPlauLoss FROM 
    (SELECT tab1.IRSpot, MIN(tab1.VegaElement*Probability) AS PlausibleLoss FROM 
        (SELECT IRSpot, IRVol, VegaElement  
        FROM SEL_VegaElementMatrix()) tab1 
    JOIN 
        (SELECT IRSpot, IRVol, Probability  
        FROM Table_Name_2) tab2 
    ON tab1.IRSpot = tab2.IRSpot AND tab1.IRVol = tab2.IRVol 
    GROUP BY tab1.IRSpot) tab3 
RIGHT JOIN 
    (SELECT IRSpot, IRVol, VegaElement  
    FROM SEL_VegaElementMatrix()) tab4 
ON tab3.PlausibleLoss = tab4.VegaElement AND tab3.IRSpot = tab4.IRSpot
```